# XPATH doing a list of element without twins

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

For the context, I can have ~300 value for a property named 'Model' for ~1500 Object named 'block', and I try to get the Model list without twins.

The XML file look like :

```
<blocks>
    <block name="toto1">
        <property... />
        <property name="Shape" value="New" />
        <property ... />
        <property name="Model" value="xxx" />
        <property ... />
    </block>

    <block name="toto2">
        <property name="Shape" value="New" />
        <property ... />
        ...
        <property name="Model" value="yyy" />
        <property ... />
    </block>
    <block name="toto3">
        <property ... />
        <property name="Shape" value="New" />
        <property ... />
        <property name="Model" value="xxx" />
        <property ... />
        <property ... />
    </block>
    <block name="toto4">
        <property ... />
        <property name="Shape" value="Old" />
        <property name="Model" value="555" />
        <property ... />
    </block>
    <block name="toto5">
        <property ... />
        <property name="Shape" value="New" />
        <property name="Model" value="zzz" />
        <property ... />
    </block>
</blocks>
```

I'm selecting the value of the value attribute who have a name attribute = 'Model' by selecting before the node parent who have a name attribut = 'Shape' = New... hmmmm.. look my path ^^' he works ! but not enough

```
//block/property[@name="Shape"][@value="New"]/parent::block/property[@name="Model"]/@value
```

I need to do this, else I get 'model' value who aren't expected..
like for 'shape = old'.
{xxx,yyy,xxx,555,zzz}

So I get {xxx,yyy,xxx,zzz} but I want {xxx,yyy,zzz}

I get a list with 1500 model value elements, and I really have ~300 unique model...

So I'm using JS with a temporary Array for avoid twins with

```
if(!shapes[Modelvalue]){shapes[shapes.length]=Modelvalue; shapes[Modelvalue]=[shapes.length];}
```

But can I do it only with Xpath pls?
The request take 4sec because numbers of Blocks..

Comment: how does `block/property` even work for that HTML - please note, stackoverflow is a strictly **english only** site

Comment: il n'y a aucun attribut `model`.  il y a des attributs `name` pouvant avoir la valeur "model" déjà que ta question est confuse, si en plus tu utilise un vocabulaire ambigu, on va pas s'en sortir. Donc tu veux récuprer toutes les occurences différentes des élements xml  dont l'attribut est `value` ayant `name="Model"`. que vient faire Shape" dans cette histoire ? --   et comme le fait remarquer **Bravo** stackoverflow est un site ou tout le monde doit s'exprimer en Anglais

Comment: i have transate ^^ but i hope what's understable :s thx for return !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use a DOMParser, because we can use ES6 methods (querySelector ...) and this gives a much clearer code.

then just use a Set ()

```js
let xmlData = `
<blocks>
    <block name="toto1">
        <property truc1="" />
        <property name="Shape" value="New" />
        <property truc2="" />
        <property name="Model" value="xxx" />
        <property truc3="" />
    </block>
    <block name="toto2">
        <property name="Shape" value="New" />
        <property truc1="" />
        <property name="Model" value="yyy" />
        <property truc2="" />
    </block>
    <block name="toto3">
        <property truc1="" />
        <property name="Shape" value="New" />
        <property truc2="" />
        <property name="Model" value="xxx" />
        <property truc3="" />
        <property truc4="" />
    </block>
    <block name="toto4">
        <property truc1="" />
        <property name="Shape" value="Old" />
        <property name="Model" value="555" />
        <property truc2="" />
    </block>
    <block name="toto5">
        <property truc1="" />
        <property name="Shape" value="New" />
        <property name="Model" value="zzz" />
        <property truc2="" />
    </block>
</blocks>`;

const parser  = new DOMParser()
  ,   docBLKs = parser.parseFromString(xmlData, "application/xml")
  ,   rSet    = new Set()
  ;
docBLKs.querySelectorAll('property[name="Shape"][value="New"]').forEach(sn=>
  {
  let model = sn.closest('block').querySelector('property[name="Model"]')
  rSet.add( model.getAttribute('value') )
  })

console.log( Array.from(rSet) )
```

Comment: Merci !! I don't understand all in your code for now :s i'm starting.... so i will understand how he works ^^ what is new set().add and the 'let' too ^^"
i already have a DOMparse function, because my XML code is load from a file with an input.. maybe that will help.. or not
querySelectorAll & querySelector are JS ?? (i just discoverd them :s ) so why Xpath ?

Comment: Edit : THX !! i have understand !!! it's because Set can't have twins.. amazing !
Is querySelectorAll faster like xpath for large amount pls ? it's not like i need to rewrite half of my code xD

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Mister Jojo !!
it's not what i expected but that works great !!
i do this:

```js
function displayShapes()
  {
  ModelAttrPath  = '//block/property[@name="Shape"][@value="New"]/parent::block/property[@name="Model"]/@value';
  ModelAttrList  = xmlDoc.evaluate(ModelAttrPath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  ModelAttrFocus = ModelAttrList.iterateNext();

  ModelList = new Set();
  while(ModelAttrFocus)
    {
    ModelList.add( ModelAttrFocus.value);
    ModelAttrFocus = ModelAttrList.iterateNext();
    }// $c(ModelList.size);

  //creat Tree dropdown
  cnt = '<div id="tree">';
  for(elements of ModelList)
    {
    cnt += '<button class="treeB">'+elements+'</button><div class="treeP"></div>';
    }
  cnt += '</div>';
  $('divMenu2').innerHTML = cnt;
  treeD(); //init du addEventListener click pour la creation du menu 
  $('tree').style.height = $('divMenu2').style.height;
  }
```

and i get my Model Tree menu in less than 1sec :) perfect !
next step looking querySelector !